# A number is not pale if and only if it has at least two consecutive digits each equal to 3, or if its last digit is divisible by 4

Tags: python, function

```
def pale(n):
    '''(int)->bool
    return A number is not pale if and only if it has at least two consecutive digit divisible by 4.
  
    >>> pale(1128)
    Fasle
    >>> pale(3443)
    True
    '''
    return n%4!=0 and n!=33
   
print(pale(5433))
```

but something wrong in answer 5433 is false but in answer is true. please recommend to me.

Comment: The logic in the body of the function seems to have no connection at all to the description of what it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look to each digit of n, not to the entire number:

```
def pale(n):
    sym = str(n)
    for idx in range(len(sym)-1): # For each digit in the number n
        if int(sym[idx])%4 == 0: # if the digit is divisible by 4
            if int(sym[idx+1])%4 == 0: # and if the next one is divisible by 4
                return True
    return False
```